# How to set "reset all code reviewer votes" in Azure Devops using CLI

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-repos

Currently trying to automate branch policy creation in AzureDevOps using the Azure CLI with Windows Powershell, is there a way to enable "Reset all code reviewer votes" when new changes are applied through the CLI?

currently have the following:

```
 az repos policy approver-count create --allow-downvotes false --blocking true --branch dev --creator-vote-counts true --enabled true --minimum-approver-count 1 --repository-id $repoID --reset-on-source-push true
```

and so far it only ticks/enables the "Reset all approval votes (does not reset votes to reject or wait)" option

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi one of the options is to use Azure DevOps REST API of [Policy Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/update?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#policyconfiguration), however you need to construct JObject arrays and use PUT Request.

what you need is on the `resetOnSourcePush` and maybe`creatorVoteCounts`

[image]

Comment: can you please help me out from the following azure function issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480321/azure-function-using-powershell-to-consume-the-data-from-an-event-hub-and-write?noredirect=1#comment122808093_69480321